# How can i maintain a session for a HTML page in Apache server?

Tags: javascript, html, session

I am new in session management for website. I created a simple [html](/questions/tagged/html) Form page with all the data. After clicking submit button, my forms input fields will disable. And the submit button changes to disconnect. This is working fine with Apache server.

Now i want a solution that when I refresh this page or load a same page in new tab, I need to show the same disabled for page. Means, do not refresh the page. I need to maintain this page when user press disconnect button. Should I use database with login details?

Any suggestions? or tutorials links?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a server-side language like PHP or something and maintain a session with some credentials.

Comment: ok . like PHP ` PHp _SESSION['username'] = "your username";`  isn't ? can i use with out any login credentials ?

Comment: Well… you could do it all client-side with local storage/cookies… but then again, what exactly are you authenticating against and what sort of "session" are you establishing here without a server-side component to begin with?

Comment: yeah got it . when i clear all the cookies , that session will overwrite . isn't ? so i should use with credentials  . OK thanks

Comment: yes, exactly.. do not store credentials in cookies, always maintain a session on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sessions are not managed by html files. You'll need to create php files like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // without this, you won't have any session
// add here code to manage your session/post data
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSSION['title'] = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
}
?>
<html>
...
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['title']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

In above example the submit will be made in the same page.

Resources:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

#### Don't use this in production. This example is for demonstration purpose only.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: Indeed. but for the example is more than enough. I don't recommend to use this code in production. It is only for illustrating the how to. For production I recommend using a framework. I use symfony 2/3.